Connect to multiple postgreql dbs on the same port
I have been searching for a solution to my problem but haven't found anything helpful yet.
I am wondering what the best approach is to tackle this issue without making changes to the configurations.
In every project, I have a docker-compose file with the following configuration:
yaml
postgres:
  image: postgres:16.2
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "password"
    POSTGRES_DB: "db_1"
  ports:
    - "5431:5432"

Currently, our environment is set up to run a script that connects to the database specified in the docker-compose file, which opens the connection.
However, if I open another project in IntelliJ and try to run the script, it fails because the port is already in use.
Ideally, I would like to find a way to connect to all the databases simultaneously.
One option would be to change the external port for each project, but I would prefer not to do that, as I am looking for a solution that does not require modifying any configuration files.

You are trying to connect to different database servers on the same port - that's your problem. Never going to work. You could run a proxy on that port, but then you'd need to reconfigure the proxy every time. You need to write enough code to have postgresql mapped to a random unused port on the host (easy, see docker manuals) and then automatically update your IDE config files with that new port number (needs a script). Alternatively, some IDEs will let you get "inside" the container and attach from there.
